# A Link Inside an iFrame That Pops Up "Photo Theater"

Tags: facebook-iframe, photo-gallery, iframe-app

I have a tab with an iframe external web page that loads...  I would love a hyperlink inside that web page to link one of my photo albums in "theater" mode so you don't leave the page. However, any link I program inside that web page just brings in that photo album inside (not popped up and not in theater mode no matter if I have the &theater in the url).

Can I get some help on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: assides from the javascript - or in addition - you might want to send facebook a feature request - it sounds like quite a useful feature!
I assume by "theater mode" you mean the way facebook displays pictures - when it blocks out the rest of the page to display a photo with all its comments...

Answer (score 0):

this is a limitation of iframes in general.  Less of a limitation and more of a security issue.  As you said.. the iframe loads and external page - a page that could essentially come from anywhere.  To protect the integrity of the site displaying this external page, the iframe can not access the page that contains it.

You might want to try opening a new window using javascript :

```
window.open ("{path_to_image}","title","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
```

as you can see there are several options that you can set to customize the popup window.

Here is another link with some [info about iframes](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/)

Comment: Yes, Lix, that exactly is what I would like...  it is a design portfolio I would like to "pop up". Check it out: http://www.facebook.com/brucechristycreative?sk=app_206396009424871

Comment: ok..so you'll have to have the photo_id and grant the application permissions to retrieve information about that photo from the graph api... 
When you make a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/{photo_id}`, within the response you will have a property called 'link'... pass that property to the `window.open()` and your user should get a new tab/window with the photo in the theater mode... alternitavly if you want to do a redirect - you'll have to user `top.location.href` to redirect the user to the same url.

Comment: Apologies...  I am a graphic designer with *some* html experience. Making calls is a bit beyond. :) So, in dreamweaver (in my mini web site I am iframing) do I surround the url in the link to the photo album address I want with some of this code you suggest above? The photo album address is: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=225044984211245&set=a.225044970877913.55003.187811151267962&type=1&theater

Comment: no worries @Bruce... basically opening a photo in the way you want is at the moment not supported by facebook. But "Poping out" a window with the photo is very possible. In your page you can place an anchor tag and set the `href` property to that url :
`<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=225044984211245&set=a.225044970877913.55003.187811151267962&type=1&theater">Link to photo</a>`

Comment: cool. guess that is the only workaround at this point. thx. what is that >Link to photo</a> part for? (I understand the _blank part ok)

Comment: its a link. the HTML "a" tag... with the "target" property you choose where to open the new window, the "href" is the location to be redirected, and the text between the "<a> <a/>" is the text that is clickable...